# Ho to do WPF MVVM Validation outside of ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

I am new to WFP, I am doing a MVVM project and trying to figure things out... I read a lot about validation but didn't find what I want.
I don't want to put validation logic in the ViewModel, or the View. I want to keep validations into the Business Logic layer, and only there, that's a separate project, presumably could be used with any datasource or UI so I can't put WPF specific stuff in it.
I would like to use FluentValidation but I don't know how to link it in my ViewModel.
Let's say I have an entry form with one field, the Save button is requesting the Save method from the Business logic, business logic throws a ValidationException if the field is empty with the corresponding message ("Please type something").
How do I link this to the View/ViewModel to reflect it to the user?

Any help is appreciated, sorry if the question is dumb, this WPF is hard :)

EDIT, reply to John Odom: I've got to the point where in my ViewModel I have the Save command which does something like

```
           try
            {
                EditedItem= itemService.PersistItem(EditedItem);

            }
            catch (ValidationException ex)
            {

              foreach (var result in ex.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Property name: " + result.PropertyName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + result.ErrorMessage);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
```

I would like to link the info in the CATCH section with my view, and show the error info to the user

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please show us what you have attempted so far?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to do this? Because the purpose of MVVM is separating these kind of concerns from business logic.

Comment: Validations to me are part of business logic. If I want to create a web UI for the same system, I would have to duplicate the validations. Unless I am missing something...

Comment: If you validate the _user input_ the validation part is View's or ViewModel's job. Business logic should validate your own errors like null check. For reusability you can create [ValidationRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms753962(v=vs.100).aspx)'s and use them in your Views.

Comment: Can I use these ValidationRules in a separate assembly? I don't want my WPF UI View to "know" for example that valid Age Range is 21-130 as in that example. If I have that, and then have another web interface, I will have to repeat the 21-130 info there too. This kind of validation logic I want to be provided just once, and outside of WPF UI assembly . The user input validation may be the View/ViewModel's job, let them do it, but the information about what is valid and what not I still think is business logic job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can have a separate Label on the UI,hide it initially.Bind isvisible and content in view model.
Whenever there is exception make the Label visible and set its content in the Viewmodel.

Comment: That's easy, thanks! It works. 
Just that I have one label showing all errors. I'm trying now to get it to work similar to "typical" WPF validation errors, one per field, but I still want the code to be generic. I think I need to study indexed properties, or something, because from the FluentValidator I do get a collection of errors with message and each fieldname

Comment: Please select correct answer if u think it's answered :) . Also if u like the solution 1 up please.